# filter2D openCV function error

Tags: c#, matlab, opencv, cat

I m using this line with this function but I have an error.

```
filter2D(GaussKernel,conspic1,GaussKernel.depth(),split(GaussKernel,KernelAchrSplit),Point(-1,-1),0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

Kernel and conspic1 are Mat object. I suppose I have a problem with the kernel, because I don'tknow any function that returns me it. So I use split function

This is how to use the function for C++:

```
void filter2D(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int ddepth, InputArray kernel, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1), double delta=0, int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

The error I have is:

invalid use of void expression

Comment: What language are you using? The tags say C#, but your original question mentioned C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have to do is translating from Matlab:

```
GaussKernel=fspecial('gaussian',maxhw,sigma);
conspic=filter2(GaussKernel,conspic,'same'); //Gaussian snoothing in each orientation
```

What I did is:

```
GaussianBlur(maxhw,GaussKernel,Size(0,0),1,1,BORDER_DEFAULT;
//setting 1,1 ; i m setting the Gaussian kernel standard deviation as 
//the paramether sigma in Matlab first line

filter2D(GaussKernel,conspic1,GaussKernel.depth(),split(GaussKernel,KernelAchrSplit),Point(-1,-1),0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
//I know I don t have to use split for the kernel paramether, but I suppose I have
// to use GaussKernel Mat object's kernel and I don t know how get it
```

Comment: I would suggest you read the documentation I linked to. `cv::GaussianBlur` does not generate a Gaussian kernel, it does the blurring with parameters that you define. You appear to call the function correctly. Your second call to `cv::filter2D` is unnecessary. Also, this should be an edit to your question, not an answer.

Comment: _%Softening Gaussian filter_ 
_% Gaussian parameters as functions of image size_ . . . . . . . .     .  . . . . .... ,....
    maxhw = max(0,floor(min(r/2,c/2) - 1)); . . . . . . .   . . .  . . . . .. . . . .. . . . .. .  . . . .  . . . .. . . . . .. . . . . . . . . . 
    sigma = max(r,c)*0.025; . . . . . . .. . . . . . . .. . . . . . . .. . . . .. . . .. . . .. . . . .. . . .. . . . .. . . .. . . .  .  . .
    GaussKernel=fspecial('gaussian',maxhw,sigma);  .  . 

    _% Gaussian smoothing in each orientation_
    conspic=filter2(GaussKernel,conspic,'same');
    conspic1 = conspic1 + conspic;

Comment: this is what I need to do. Thanks for helping! Can you say me how to go down in the comments! I can posts what I did in C for this lines. Now I m not sure about  sigma utilization in C

Answer (score 0):

You receive your error because `cv::split()` returns `void`, and `cv::filter2D()` expects a `cv::Mat` parameter as the fourth argument.

You can create an arbitrary kernel simply by creating a floating-point `cv::Mat` and filling the values with whatever you wish. One example:

```
cv::Mat kern = cv::Mat::ones(15,15, CV_32FC1)/225;
```

OpenCV also provides a few functions to calculate common kernels, such as [`cv::getGaussianKernel()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#getgaussiankernel).

However, since it looks like you want to do Gaussian filtering, it is probably simpler to use [`cv::GaussianBlur()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur).